# FPC Cable Repair

Tags: repair, fpc

Is it possible to repair this type of FPC cable? I am a filmmaker and have just basic soldering skills and know this type of repair is beyond me. This is from a LCD Touchscreen. Is this cable repairable?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried this type of repair, but I have pulled apart plenty of FPC cables for analysis (to make sure they were manufactured properly) .

In the past I have been able to use an exacto knife and carefully scrape off the kapton layer (you'll need a microscope), after the power planes are exposed it may be possible to solder them together with another flat piece of metal such as copper tape.

The problem with this type of repair is it may be too high resistance for the current carried by the cable, or the repair could be too large for the space that the cable was originally in.

In my opinion, its not worth it. It will be a difficult repair. Try and get another cable from the manufacturer or buy a used or broken unit and use that cable.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The manufacturer no longer makes this cable, and I am on the lookout for a used replacement. Another followup question if I may... The input for the monitor connection is a 16 Pin Lemo Connector that is soldered to the broken FPC cable. Would it be possible to create a cable that bypasses the need for the FPC cable and goes from the 16 Pin connector to the FPC connector socket on the logic board? There is plenty of space in the unit to do so.

Comment: If the manufacturer no longer makes it and you can't easily get the cable out of a for-parts unit, it should also be possible to have one custom-made by a small-runs PCB manufacturer too. I know PCBway does flat-flex, at least last I had cause to use them.

Comment: The resistance of FPC will be higher than solder or a typical wire anyway so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @Mra yes you could just solder wires between the two PCBs. The data connections if any may not like the different wires of this if they are matched impedance type data lines.

Comment: @Passerby Depends on the weight of the cable, 0.33 or 0.5oz yes. I wouldn't be surprised if the cable was made with 1oz or 2oz copper seeing as it carries power

Comment: @mraaron895 it would cost at least 100-150$ and whatever time it would take for someone to reverse engineer it.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion only: this cable is most likely repairable **IF** the person doing the repair has the experience and the skills to do the work.

I would scrape the Kapton layer from the copper, then use either copper foil (thin, flexible) or copper braid (thick, not flexible if saturated with solder).

Be sure to insulate the actual break itself so that you don't short to the conductor on the back side of the flex strip.

Obviously, you will need to repair the conductors on both sides of the flex strip.

See if you can find someone local to you who might be able to do the work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm in the San Francisco Bay Area, but am unsure of where to find someone who has the experience and is willing to take this on. Do you have any recommendations of places I could post such a job to? My budget for this would be $400 to $600. Is this a feasible and an appropriate bid?

Comment: @mraaron895 Honestly, I would first check on ebay or similar to see if anyone is selling another one of whatever this cable came from. You'll probably be able to find a broken one cheap, and then just take the cable from that to replace the one in your not-broken whatever-it-is.